# Youtube video is sticking with the colorbox in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, youtube

Im working with `http://204.197.252.143/~acornins/`.

I just encountered an issue in displaying youtube video using firefox browser.

When I click the "Enquire Now" button in the left, a contact form will popup.

The problem is the youtube video will stick with pop up in firefox and messes up the appearance.

[image]

In Google chrome, the display is okay.

The youtube embed code is

**Q: What will be the best solution in this firefox issue? Can I solve it using css?**

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the answer.

In my embed code, i added some parameter block `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` and embed parameter `wmode="opaque"`.

My embed code now is:

```
<object width="340" height="285"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/Msqyj26_Il8?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;showinfo=0"></param><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
```

Cheers!